# Fewer than expected purity scores in PCA analysis

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means, pca

I'm trying to plot the line graph of purity scores against the captured variances in PCA. The goal is to plot the line graph of purity scores against the captured variances of 89% and 99% only. In my code when the components/dimensions are 2 it captures 89% of variance and and when components/dimensions are 4 it captures 99% of variance.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

df = pd.read_csv("clustering.csv")
X10_df = df.drop("Class",axis = 1) #feature matrix
Y10_df = df["Class"] #Target vector
X10_df = np.array(X10_df)
Y10_df = np.array(Y10_df)
scaler = StandardScaler() # Standardizing the data
df_std = scaler.fit_transform(X10_df)
pca = PCA()
pca.fit(df_std)
purity = []
n_comp = range(2,5)
for k in n_comp :
    pca = PCA(n_components = k)
    pca.fit(df_std)
    pca.transform(df_std)
    scores_pca = pca.transform(df_std)
    kmeans_pca = KMeans(n_clusters=3, init ='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10, random_state=0)
    pred_y12 = kmeans_pca.fit_predict(scores_pca)
    purity13 = purity_score(Y10_df, pred_y12)
    purity.append(purity13)
```

Below function calculates the purity score :

```
def purity_score(y_true, y_pred):
    contingency_matrix = metrics.cluster.contingency_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
    return np.sum(np.amax(contingency_matrix, axis=0)) / np.sum(contingency_matrix)
```

However, while I have four variance scores, I only have three purity scores. I expected to have four purity scores so that I could create a plot of the variance vs purity.

Why there are only three purity scores?

Here is the link to my dataset file : https://gofile.io/d/3CgFTi

Comment: Wait, is this question really about matplotlib or about the PCA library?

Comment: Thanks Paul for the edit. I had posted the error message as per the stackoveflow guidelines.

Comment: Agree that it's good to include tracebacks, but the question isn't really about matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because when you using for loop with a range, the last number in the range is ignored. So in a range(2,5), it will go 2, 3, 4 and then quite the loop. Please read on for loop in Python.